# What are the pros & cons of changing companies to keep one’s upward career growth?

Tags: career-development, promotion, politics

If you notice a trend where others (including new hires) are directly placed or promoted above your position—for whatever reason—is the option of leaving the company the only way to find a higher role fast and keep your upward career growth constant and linear?

What considerations do I need to make to assess the advantages and drawbacks of doing so?

Comment: Leaving the company without addressing the issue is dismissing an opportunity for growth ;-)

Comment: Growth is never constant and linear and that is a good thing. WOudl you really want to reach the top level you are going to reach (very few will make it past second line management and most of those started out higher than that) in five years and be stuck there for the next 40?

Answer (score 2):

> What considerations do I need to make to assess the advantages and
>   drawbacks of doing so?

First, 100% of nobody will ever complain that you left a company for a better position. The key is how professionally you handle leaving & how polite you are to the previous company when you leave.

The key is to not burn bridges. Don’t act in the heat of the moment. You might want to mention that seeing new hires come on board above you inspired you to look elsewhere, but don’t dwell on that at all. Let the company figure it out for themselves. If you feel that way, you can’t be the only one.

But leaving a company for a better position & salary is the number 1 reason anyone leaves a company. So it’s not unusual at all as awkward as it might seem.